# Does Ocarina of Time have the same controls as Majora's Mask (3D)?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

I just finished Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time 3D, and I heard that there's a sequel (Majora's Mask). I was just wondering if it has the same controls and bottom-screen UI as OOT. I'm also wondering if things like using Proxy and a bow and arrow are the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a person who HAS Majora's mask AND OOT, I can say the controls are the same. The items are slightly different, though. You WILL learn fast, it is very similar to OOT.

Comment: I'd add that Wind Waker, Twilight Princess, and Skyward Sword are all also pretty close to the same in terms of controls (though they vary in other ways, most notably art style, which would include the UI).  Breath of the Wild is much more of a departure from these in gameplay, but still manages to be pretty familiar in many respects.

Comment: Majora's Mask 3D also adds camera controls if you have either a new3DS or a circle pad pro. Though I'm of the opinion that the original N64 game is the better way to experience it... they made some very questionable decisions in the remake.